# Create a Java application that keeps your computer from going idle without moving the mouse all over the place?

Tags: java

I need to create a simple application to keep my computer from idling and going to sleep.

I'd prefer it to be in java, but am happy to look at other solutions as long as I don't need to install a 3rd party application.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other questions. That asked for a C solution, this asked for a Java solution.

Comment: And yet the duplicate is tagged with [tag:java] and the accepted answer is Java-based, with a solution that is very similar to the one in your own answer. In other words, it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I found this when searching for a solution:

https://code.joejag.com/2013/move-your-mouse-pointer-with-java.html

However, it didn't quite work for me since it moved the mouse pointer all over the place at random. This means I could only use the application when I was *not* using my computer

https://code.joejag.com/2013/move-your-mouse-pointer-with-java.html

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.Random;

public class MouseMover {
    public static final int FIVE_SECONDS = 5000;
    public static final int MAX_Y = 400;
    public static final int MAX_X = 400;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Random random = new Random();
        while (true) {
            robot.mouseMove(random.nextInt(MAX_X), random.nextInt(MAX_Y));
            Thread.sleep(FIVE_SECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

#### I modified the solution to better suit my needs:

This version gets the mouse pointer's current location and moves the mouse to where it already is. From a user perspective the mouse doesn't move, but it *does* prevent the computer from going idle.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class MouseJiggle {
    public static final int SLEEP_MILLIS = 60*1000;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        while (true) {
            Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            robot.mouseMove(point.x, point.y);
            System.out.println("Mouse Moved!!");
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_MILLIS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not change power settings to just have it never idle or sleep?

Comment: You don't always have control over it.

Comment: Read the whole answer, @CardinalSystem, it compares what I found and the true solution which doesn't move the mouse.

Comment: @Dom same reason that YouTube doesn't require the power settings to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, you can call the WinAPI [`SetThreadExecutionState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) function to prevent the computer from sleeping.

To achieve this, first I created a class file with native function definitions:

```
package com.example.natives;

public class WindowsSleep {

    private static final boolean IS_WINDOWS;

    static {
        IS_WINDOWS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win");
        System.load("windows-sleep.dll");
    }

    private static native void preventSleep();

    private static native void allowSleep();

    public static void doPreventSleep() {
        if (IS_WINDOWS)
            preventSleep();
        else
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This operation only works on Windows machines");
    }

    public static void doAllowSleep() {
        if (IS_WINDOWS)
            allowSleep();
        else
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This operation only works on Windows machines");
    }

}
```

Then I used [javah](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) to generate the following [header file](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-files/):

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_example_natives_WindowsSleep */

#ifndef _Included_com_example_natives_WindowsSleep
#define _Included_com_example_natives_WindowsSleep
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_example_natives_WindowsSleep
 * Method:    preventSleep
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_natives_WindowsSleep_preventSleep
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

/*
 * Class:     com_example_natives_WindowsSleep
 * Method:    allowSleep
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_natives_WindowsSleep_allowSleep
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

After creating the header file, I wrote the following [C++](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) code:

```
#include "windows-sleep.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <Windows.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_natives_WindowsSleep_preventSleep(JNIEnv *, jclass) {
    SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | ES_CONTINUOUS);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_natives_WindowsSleep_allowSleep(JNIEnv *, jclass) {
    SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS);
}
```

Then I used a [makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) to compile it:

```
# Variables
CC = g++
JNI_PATH = C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_202/include
JNI_MD_PATH = $(JNI_PATH)/win32
CFLAGS = -Wall -I'$(JNI_PATH)' -I'$(JNI_MD_PATH)' -shared

# Output file
OUTPUT = windows-sleep.dll

# Source file
SOURCE = windows-sleep.cpp

# Rule to build the DLL
all: $(OUTPUT)

$(OUTPUT): $(SOURCE)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

# Rule to clean the build artifacts
clean:
    rm -f $(OUTPUT)
```

After compiling the DLL, I was able to call `doPreventSleep` to prevent my computer from sleeping. Keep in mind that [you have to keep calling this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27652326/5645656) - you cannot just invoke it once. Here's an example:

```
ThreadFactory factory = r -> {
    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    // Use daemon threads so they don't keep the JVM alive
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    return thread;
};

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(factory);
// Call doPreventSleep every 5 minutes
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> WindowsSleep.doPreventSleep(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

// Do stuff

executor.shutdownNow();
```