# How to call of SetThreadExecutionState correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

The following snippet is supposed to prevent a Windows machine to go to sleep *while an important operation is finished* (running a different thread):

```cs
[Flags]
private enum EXECUTION_STATE : uint
{
    ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040,
    ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000,
    ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002,
    ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern EXECUTION_STATE SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE esFlags);

public async Task KeepAwakeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) 
{
  while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    var result = SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED); // (XXX)
    if (result == 0)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("SetThreadExecutionState failed.");
    }

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
}
```

1. I'm not sure whether `ES_CONTINUOUS` is needed too (i.e. `var result = SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);`).

   Can anyone explain the difference between `ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED` and `ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED` when used in the sample above?
2. I read somewhere that `SetThreadExecutionState` applies only to the current thread. Is that true? Can anybody elaborate on the precise meaning?

I have read [1] and for some reason it confuses me every time I read it.

Resources:

- [1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate
- [2] [Prevent screen from sleeping with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045701/prevent-screen-from-sleeping-with-c-sharp/)
- [3] [SetThreadExecutionState is not working when called from windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870280/setthreadexecutionstate-is-not-working-when-called-from-windows-service/)

Comment: 1: It is not needed since the code calls it repeatedly.  2:  The ConfigureAwait() call prevents the use of ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED, the thread that turns it on must be the same thread that turns it off.

Comment: `while (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)` looks wrong - it'll only loop if cancellation has already been requested and I don't think you can "un-cancel" a cancellationToken.

Comment: @HansPassant: So now I understand that one should not use `ConfigureAwait(false)` but what happens when it it actually used? I basically set for *different* threads that they should not sleep, right? 
@Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, I fixed it. Thank you.